# Logstash, add index for every package in project

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

i have a logs from different packages,

for example,

```
com.example.package1.subpackage1.MyClass
com.example.package1.subpackage2.MyClass
com.example.package2.subpackage1.MyClass  
com.example.package2.subpackage2.MyClass
```

i want to create index for `package1` and `package2`,

at the current moment logstash configuration like this:

```
filter {
    if "package1" in [logger_name] {
      mutate {
        add_tag => "package1"
      }
    }

    if "package2" in [logger_name] {
      mutate {
        add_tag => "package2"
      }
    }
}

output {
    if "package1" in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
        index => "package1"
      }
    }

    if "package2" in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
        index => "package2"
      }
    }
}
```

But every time, when i add new package, i need restart logstash with new configuration, is it possible create more generic config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grok{} filter to pull the name out into a logstash field, and then you can reference that in the output{} stanza.

Comment: how to extract `package1` from `com.example.package1.subpackage1.MyClass` via grok?

Comment: Skim the grok man page, test things in the grok debugger, and then ask questions here or on IRC if it doesn't work.